# What happens if declare some variables as static and these variables are initialized inside recursive function?

Tags: c++, c

What happens if declare some variables as static inside function  and these variables are initialized inside the same recursive function? Is the value initialized everytime we make a recursive call?

Comment: `static` variables within a function scope are initialized only once, the first time the function is called.  Recursive calls will not re-initialize them.

Comment: No. The variable will be initialized once, before program execution.

Comment: Recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions. There is nothing special about recursion.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin The static variables will be initialised when the function is first called.

Comment: @john Strictly speaking `static` variables ae initialized on the program startup, together with other statically allocated variables (such as globals). It is convenient from the programmer point of view to think of these being initialized first time the function is entered. But the two behaviors are indistinguishable from C point of view anyway.

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: If this were about C, it would be a well-stated question. It does not need to refer to a particular program, as it can be briefly answered with a simple reference to sect 6.2.4 para 3: "An object whose identifier is declared ... with the storage-class specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup." An answer would serve a much more useful purpose than closing the question. VTRO (and not the first to do so). (I think the same question about C++ is also answerable.)

Comment: C and C++ are not the same. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @EugeneSh. This is incorrect. They are initialized when first encountered. You can verify this by initializing a static with a global, and changing the global inside `main` before entering the function with the static.

Comment: @Aganju You can't initialize `static` variable with a non-constant (try it: https://ideone.com/SkXL5O). This is true for `C`, I don't know about C++.

Comment: @Aganju I would like to see your claim proven by a [example].

Answer (score 0):

No. Local variables with `static` storage duration are initialized exactly once (C) or at most once (C++), regardless of recursive or repeated calls to the function in which they are declared.

The C standard is quite clear. All `static` variables, whether at file or local scope, are initialised once, prior to the program startup:

> An object whose identifier is declared… with the storage-class specifier `static`, has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup. (§6.2.4 / para 3).

If you're referring to C++, the rules are a lot more complicated, in part because unlike C, C++ allows initialisation using a non-constant expression. That means that the initialisation of a variable could be externally visible. (For example, the initialiser could call a function with side effects.) For the case of a local `static` variable, the relevant section is `[stmt.dcl]` (§8.8); paragraph 4 reads, in part:

> Dynamic initialization of a block-scope variable with static storage duration (6.7.5.1) or thread storage duration (6.7.5.2) is performed the first time control passes through its declaration; such a variable is considered initialized upon the completion of its initialization.

So the variable is initialized at most once, no matter how many times the function is called (and whether or not it is called recursively), but the initializer won't be executed at all if the declaration is never reached. (The variable will, however, have been zero-initialised prior prior to program startup. See `[basic.start.static]` (§6.9.3.2).)

Comment: Your answer doesn't take into account cases like `int f() { static int x = f(); }`. Here, when `f` is re-entered, the initialization has not yet completed.